# Controlar CSS dinamicamente via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site, e também um gerenciador de conteúdo para ele, no gerenciador eu controlo as imagens do site e os textos, gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de eu controlar a cor da fonte e o tipo da fonte dos textos, ou seja, no gerenciador, ter um color picker (ou algo similar) para o usuário escolher qual a cor da fonte de determinado texto, e também alguma forma de escolher qual o tipo da fonte (Times New Roman, Arial, Comic Sans, e outras).
Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Olha, tem diversas formas de se fazer isso. Pode gerar um arquivo.css no servidor... Pode guardar trechos css e renderizar na tela... etc. Deverá escolher uma forma e fazer. Acredito que achará muito conteúdo a respeito na internet

Comment: Poisé , eu sei que existem diversas formas de fazer isso, por isso pedi Sugestões ...

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta parece ampla demais para obter uma resposta concreta, por isso os votos negativos. Enfim, você pode obter o hexadecimal de uma cor através de um Color Picker e salvá-lo em um banco de dados, por exemplo, algo como `#FF0000`. Depois você carrega essa informação e define via javascript.

Comment: Agora, olhando por um outro ângulo, talvez você esteja perguntando sobre [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com) ou [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com), que são editores de texto que você pode incorporar no seu gerenciador.

Comment: Exato , estou pensando em ter um color picker para selecionar a cor e então salvar o código hexadecimal ou rgb e mudar no css da pagina principal

Answer (score 2):

É possível escrever CSS dinâmico com PHP **SIM**, aconselho? bom, para iniciantes é uma boa ideia mas se você já tem algum conhecimento em `javascript` seja ele intermediário/avançado, já pode usar ferramentas mais apropriadas para isso como [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)/[SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), atreladas a ferramentas como [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), eles funcionam muito bem.

para escrever `CSS` com `PHP` basta definir seu `header` e importa-lo para a página onde se quer estilizar exemplo...

**PHP**

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css");
$cor_fundo = "#999";    

?>

body {
background: <?=$cor_fundo?>;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.php" type="text/css" />
```

Tendo isso em mente, você poderá manipular as variáveis manualmente, ou construir um painel para interagir com o código...

Comment: Eu conseguiria controlar essa variável (nesse seu exemplo $cor_fundo)  por outra pagina (a pagina do gerenciador), ai quando eu mudar a cor e salvar, ela é salva (ou enviada) no css da pagina principal ?

Comment: consegue sim, e tem várias formas, uma delas é criar um arquivo json com as configurações das variáveis, e no painel ler, editar e salvar essas configurações, no arquivo php(css) você lê essas configurações e as aplica...